# Передача значения поля БД в backgroundImage div'a в js функции

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

У меня имеется большое поле (div), в котором находятся 12 div меньшего размера. При нажатии на кнопку, вызывается функция js, которая чистит большое поле от маленьких div'ов. Далее мне необходимо создать снова 12 div в этом большом поле с другими значениями, которые я получаю из БД.
Изначально у меня имелось 12 div'ов с следующими id=[1,2,3,4,5,.....,12], им соответствуют какие-либо ссылки на картинки из БД. Теперь мне необходимо получить div'ы с id=[13,14,15,16,...,24], которым соответствуют уже другие ссылки на картинки.
Сами div мне создать удалось, но вот присвоить им ссылки на изображения из БД никак не выходит. Если я задаю ссылку на картинку напрямую, то все работает. Однако мне необходимо получить их непосредственно из бд. currentPage - это текущая страница с блоками. На первой странице - показывает первые 12 блоков, на второй следующие 12 и т.д. id_animal - это ключ, его номер соответствует номеру блока, img_link - ссылка на картинку, которая мне так необходима. Помогите разобраться. Сейчас у меня имеется файл с запросом .php :

```
<?php

$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, "select id_animal, img_link from animal_table;") or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($conn));
    $to_encode = array  ();  
if($result1)
{
    while($row = $result1->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $to_encode[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($to_encode);
}
$result1->close();
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Также в наличии сама функция .js :

```
function NumPage(number){
$currentPage=number.id.replace(/[^-0-9]/gim,'');
alert($currentPage );

function getNewAnimalBlocks() 
{   

    var $main = document.getElementById('animalMainField');
    $main.innerHTML = '';
    i=($currentPage*12-11);
    while (i<($currentPage*12+1)) 
        {
            var div=document.createElement('block'+i);
            div.id = "block"+i;
            div.className = "animalBlock";
            //div.style.backgroundImage="url(./img/picture/7.png)"

            $.getJSON('./pages/database/getImg.php', function(data) 
            {

                $.each(data, function(id_animal, img_link) 
                {
                    console.log(id_animal + ':' + img_link);
                    if (id_animal==i)
                    {

                        div.style.backgroundImage=img_link;
                        $("#block" + id_animal).style.backgroundImage("url("+img_link+")");
                    }
                });
            });
            console.log(div);
            animalMainField.appendChild(div);
            console.log(div);
            i+=1;
        }
} 

getNewAnimalBlocks();

}
```

Comment: Хотя бы в консоли браузера посмотреть можно было, идет ли запрос на сервер и что он возвращает ?

Comment: Запрос идёт нормально, возвращается в виде [{"ключ1":"значение1"}, {"ключ2":"значение2"}]. Но функция getJSON  попросту игнорируется. Я также пробовал передать массив to_encode через событие onclick, переместив вызов выше по коду. Массив заполнен похожим образом, но через знаки => , вот только в событии в консоли вместо массива выводит f Array () {undefined}. Я только начал работать с js и php, и решения в интернете мне не помогли, поэтому прошу помочь разобраться с проблемой здесь☺